# Using Sage as a Python library (Windows)

Tags: python, matrix, virtual-machine, sage

I'm writing code that is really heavy on linear algebra, specifically matrix operations. Because the matrices I'm using are very large, I'm running out of memory when I use the SymPy library. I think I can do what I want to in with Sage, but for my purposes I can't run my code in a VM. It has to be on my host OS. Without going so far as to install Ubuntu or something, is there a way I could add Sage to use as a library in my Python code? My Python version is 3.4, OS is Windows 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sage can only use its own Python, if that makes sense.  On Windows there are a lot of problems with certain components of Sage compiling properly (non-Python components, of course) which is why there is not a 'native port', though Cygwin should work okay if that is an option for you.  From what I hear it's not too difficult to set up an Ubuntu partition on a Windows machine, though I have no personal experience with this.

(By the way, it's possible that Octave would be a good choice for you, based on your description, or R, which is actually a component of Sage.)